# Loop through lines of a .txt file to generate nomenclature

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse, nomenclature, l3regex

I am a complete newbie in the world of macros but I need to define a command that takes the content of a .txt file and uses it to add nomenclature entries. My .txt file looks like this:

```
hPSCs: Human pluripotent stem cells
CMs: Cardiomyocytes
hPSC-CMs: hPSC-derived cardiomyocytes
```

And I want my command to essentially do the following:

```
\nomenclature{hPSCs}{Human pluripotent stem cells}
\nomenclature{CMs}{Cardiomyocytes}
\nomenclature{hPSC-CMs}{hPSC-derived cardiomyocytes}
```

For all the lines of the .txt file. In other words, I want to:

- Open .txt file
- Read each line of the .txt file. Then:

  - Split the text in two parts at delimiter, in my case ":". Let's called them `1` and `2`
  - Use the two parts to build add a nomenclature entry. So it would be `\nomenclature{1}{2}`

It would me take no time to do it in any programming language, but I really don't know where to start in Latex. I'd be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a somewhat simpler solution, using the basic TeX `\read` command. The file is supposed to be in `nominal.txt`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
% Check that we don't use existing commands
\newcommand*\mytextfile{}
\newread\mytextfile
\newcommand*\donomencl{}
\def\donomencl#1:#2\par{\nomenclature{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand*\lastreadline{\par}

\begin{document}
% \nomenclature{hPSCs}{Human pluripotent stem cells}
% \nomenclature{CMs}{Cardiomyocytes}
% \nomenclature{hPSC-CMs}{hPSC-derived cardiomyocytes}

\openin\mytextfile=nomencl.txt
\loop\unless\ifeof\mytextfile %
  \read\mytextfile to \nomenline
  \ifx\nomenline\lastreadline
  \else \expandafter\donomencl \nomenline\par
  \fi
\repeat
\closein\mytextfile

Some text 

\printnomenclature 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works perfectly as expected, thank you. Would you mind explaining (briefly) the code? I really want to be more confident with macros

Answer (score 0):

Here, I redefine `\nomenclature` just to show (detokenize) what is being invoked.  However, the approach reads the file, parses by line with a `:` separator., and constructs a `\nomenclature` invocation using the data from the two parts of the line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{readarray}
%\usepackage{listofitems}% IS LOADED BY readarray
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{nom.txt}
hPSCs: Human pluripotent stem cells
CMs: Cardiomyocytes
hPSC-CMs: hPSC-derived cardiomyocytes
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\readarraysepchar{\\}
\readdef{nom.txt}\nomdata
\setsepchar{\\/:}
\ignoreemptyitems
\readlist*\nomlist{\nomdata}
\def\tmp{}
\foreachitem\z\in\nomlist[]{%
  \itemtomacro\nomlist[\zcnt,1]\theacr
  \itemtomacro\nomlist[\zcnt,2]\thedescr
  \def\tmp{\expandafter\nomenclature\expandafter{\theacr}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\expandafter{\thedescr}%
}

Testing nomenclature

\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ended up using the simpler approach, but thank you!